# What is the regex breadth-first search algorithm that the Rust regex crate uses?

Tags: regex, rust, breadth-first-search, dfa, nfa

I've been implementing my own regex library recently, and have finished `regex -> NFA -> DFA`. I ran the DFA, and it worked. Is there a way to use a breadth-first search algorithm (like Rust's regex crate) to get matches? I've looked everywhere for an algorithm for breadth-first search regex matching, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: [The source code is available](https://github.com/rust-lang/regex)

Comment: @Shepmaster -- Yes, I know. The thing is I don't want to dig in a source code without any information.

Comment: If you are relying on https://kean.github.io/post/regex-matcher as a source, you should be aware that not everyone who writes blogs on the internet knows what they are talking about. (Nor does everyone who comments on SO, of course.)

Comment: @rici -- Yes, I am using that as a source.

Comment: @xilpex: "breadth-first search" is what you do when you use the traditional NFA-to-DFA conversion by subset construction. The subset construction *is* a breadth-first search. When that author describes this as a "new algorithm", what they mean is "new to my understanding". (That's very common, both in the software world and elsewhere. We all seem to tend to believe that something we just learned has never been learned by anyone before ever.)

Comment: @rici -- Hmm... Ok. So what algorithm does Rust and RE2 use?

Comment: Also, the thing that is complicated in real-life regex libraries is "correctly" handling regex captures. The basic ideas behind matching a regex have been known for decades. But regexes are usually ambiguous; that is, they do not automatically produce a single unambiguous CFG. That means that there is more than one way to associate a sub-expression (a capture) with actual text. And that means that you need to define the "correct" match and find it. Those things are tricky.

Comment: RE2's algorithm is the subject of a very useful series of blogposts by Russ Cox. I don't have the URL handy but it should be easy enough to find. Those posts are definitely worthwhile reading. And rereading. And reading again until you understand everything. And then digging out his references and reading them. But the basis is precisely the subset construction.

Comment: I don't know anything about the Rust library. But I imagine it is similar.

Comment: https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/ Happy reading.

Comment: Yes, the Rust library is based directly on Russ Cox's article and his RE2 implementation.

Comment: @rici -- Forgive my ignorance, but even after reading the article, I was unable to understand how to get regex matches.

Comment: What do you mean by "get a match"? Know where it starts and ends?

Comment: @rici -- Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: Perhaps it would be good to ask that precise question. :-)

Comment: For RE2, the algorithm is developed through https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp3.html, with the specific question about finding the limits answered in the section "Does the regexp match a substring of the string? If so, where?". This question is not relevant to writing a lexer, of course. The lexer always starts the match precisely at the current input point.

Comment: It's the second article that you want if you care about the details of getting match and capture locations: https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp2.html --- This is the article that goes into detail on how to extend the Thompson VM to support capturing groups. The third article is mostly about painting broad strokes of how RE2 specifically works. (Although, it does contain the very useful nugget about reversing the DFA to find the starting location.)

Comment: To be clear, @BurntSushi5 is the primary author of the Rust regex crate — previous comments from them should be considered the gold-standard.